# C# Combining two Images - Scaling

Tags: c#, image, scaling

I've tried to code a tool which combines two images and saves it as one.
So my images were like this:
[First digit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foipJ.png)
and
[Second digit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQV8A.png)
You can see, I left some space on the right for digit 1 and some space on the left for digit 2. Both of the images are 1920x1080

But when I'm combining these, I'm getting something like that:
[Both digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsysO.png)
Thats my code:

```
    private void CombineTwo(Image source1, Image source2, string FileName1, string FileName2)
    {
        Image target = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(target);
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        graphics.DrawImage(source1, 0, 0);
        graphics.DrawImage(source2, 0, 0);
        graphics.Save();
        string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string path = desktop + "\\1&2\\" + FileName1[0] + FileName2[0] + ".png";
        target.Save(@path, ImageFormat.Png);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i1 = 0; i1 <= 0; i1++)
        {
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 <= 9; i2++)
            {
                string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                string path1 = desktop + "\\1\\" + i1 + ".png";
                string path2 = desktop + "\\2\\" + i2 + ".png";
                CombineTwo(Image.FromFile(@path1), Image.FromFile(@path2), i1 + "", i2 + "");
            }
        }
    }
```

So it seems like, there is something wrong with scaling I guess, whats the problem?

Comment: You should set the dpi resolution of both bitmaps to that of the Graphics object before drawing them!

Comment: Yeah, sure. That was the problem, didn't work with that stuff since that moment, but wanted to do this little project. So, great it works now, thanks a lot! :D